# Left Mouse Button for Rubber Band and Middle for panning PYQT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have some code that separately seemed to work, but once they are combined I get an error saying `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`. My goal is the have the left mouse click draw a box around the points (Later will select these points that the box is around. Have not figured that part out yet), my wheel to zoom in and out, and my center button to pan around the view. I appreciate any help.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from math import sqrt

class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos().toPoint()
        print(point)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False

        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX, minY, distance, distance)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)
            self.setScene(self._scene)



    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)

            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(True)
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            self.mousePressEvent(event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            self.mousePressEvent(handmade_event)


        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.changeRubberBand = False
            self.mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            self.mouseReleaseEvent(handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load Points')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadPoints(self):
        self.viewer.setPoints()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I updated,please retry the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is good for specifing the distinguish of `self.mousePressEvent(event)` and `QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)`

1.
**`self.mousePressEvent(event)`**
This means that recurse the event on itself.

2.
**`QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(event)`**
This means that it executes on the other , general `QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent`

**On the occasion of 1.**

Please remember,in the previous question, you made a handmade object of `LeftButton` in `MidButton`.If you made it and throw it into `self.mousePressEvent(handmade_event)`,because `handmade_event` is actually interpretted as `LeftButton`,so it executes at the just above of if `event.button() == Qt.LeftButton` codes.So,eternal recursion happens.
Please try to write return under the `LeftButton` event.The error will be stopped instead of not manipulating them at all.

**On the occasion of 2.**

This is a more general.It is very popular and doesn't burst the recursion.
Because it is not the `Viewer` mousePressEvent.
mousePressEvent is installed by default in all widget objects.
But the execution is rather attachable.
In a word, you throw the event into the other event handler.
On the occasion of 1, you throw the event into the same event handler.
So, recursion happens.

> My goal is the have the left mouse click draw a box around the points (Later will select these points that the box is around.

I updated at 13:19
If other problems happen,please ask me.

**Result**

All events are executed as the same thing.Only class Object and the type of event are probably the mark of distinguish.If we override it and write commands before it, we can regulate its execution in advance.So,the place you don't need to handle, you simply put the `mousePressEvent` at the last position.
(it is the same if the others.)

Please give it a try this code, it won't have errors.
Tips:`QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)` and `super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)` is the same thing and you can delete either of them probably.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from math import sqrt

class Point(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)
        self.rectF = QRectF(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black)

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        self._brush = brush
        self.update()

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.rectF

    def paint(self, painter=None, style=None, widget=None):
        painter.fillRect(self.rectF, self._brush)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        point = event.pos().toPoint()
        print(point)
        QGraphicsItem.hoverMoveEvent(self, event)


class Viewer(QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    rectChanged = pyqtSignal(QRect)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Viewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.origin = QPoint()
        self.changeRubberBand = False

        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.area = float()
        self.setPoints()

    def setItems(self):
            self.data = {'x': [-2414943.8686, -2417160.6592, -2417160.6592, -2417856.1783, -2417054.7618, -2416009.9966, -2416012.5232, -2418160.8952, -2418160.8952, -2416012.5232, -2417094.7694, -2417094.7694], 'y': [10454269.7008,
     10454147.2672, 10454147.2672, 10453285.2456, 10452556.8132, 10453240.2808, 10455255.8752, 10455183.1912, 10455183.1912, 10455255.8752, 10456212.5959, 10456212.5959]}
            maxX = max(self.data['x'])
            minX = min(self.data['x'])
            maxY = max(self.data['y'])
            minY = min(self.data['y'])
            distance = sqrt((maxX-minX)**2+(maxY-minY)**2)

            self.area = QRectF(minX, minY, distance, distance)
            for i,x in enumerate(self.data['x']):
                x = self.data['x'][i]
                y = self.data['y'][i]
                p = Point(x,y)
                p.setPos(x,y)
                self._scene.addItem(p)
            self.setScene(self._scene)



    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QRectF(self.area)
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)

            unity = self.transform().mapRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
            self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPoints(self):
        self._zoom = 0
        self.setItems()
        self.setDragMode(True)
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            self.origin = event.pos()
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, QSize()))
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            self.rubberBand.show()
            self.changeRubberBand = True
            return
            #QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)
            self.original_event = event
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonPress,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,handmade_event)

        super(Viewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:

            self.changeRubberBand = False
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,event)
        elif event.button() == Qt.MidButton:
            self.viewport().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            handmade_event = QMouseEvent(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease,QPointF(event.pos()),Qt.LeftButton,event.buttons(),Qt.KeyboardModifiers())
            QGraphicsView.mouseReleaseEvent(self,handmade_event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.changeRubberBand:
            self.rubberBand.setGeometry(QRect(self.origin, event.pos()).normalized())
            self.rectChanged.emit(self.rubberBand.geometry())
            QGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent(self,event)
        super(Viewer, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = Viewer(self)
        self.btnLoad = QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load Points')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadPoints)

        VBlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)

        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)

    def loadPoints(self):
        self.viewer.setPoints()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for the very well explain answer about why I was getting the error. That makes a lot of sense. When I run the code and load the points, If the user is zoomed in and tries to draw a box with the left mouse button the viewport will still pan. Is there a way to not make the view only pan with the center button?

Comment: Ok,please give me some time for thinking it.And while doing it,I may put an ask about it.If it is out of my skill,please don't feel bad.

Comment: @laxer I retry your code, if I use leftbutton, the rect appears.but at the current time, the screen moves.Do you want to stop the moving?

Comment: @laxer please try to delete `QGraphicsView.mousePressEvent(self,event)` in the LeftButton and put return there.Do you hope it?

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! I was way over thinking it. Thank you updating the code to show me what I was missing

Comment: I have focused on your error.sorry.I was not aware of your purpose.